# How to create a Yup validation for a Map in React, given Yup.map() does not exist?

Tags: reactjs, validation, yup

I have a field called "myMapField", which needs to be a map with string keys to a string value and I also need to validate the keys in the map against elements in some other field called "myArrayField".

Example: myMapField can look like

```
{"employee1": "code1", "employee2": "code2"}
```

and myArrayField can look like

```
["employee1", "employee2", "employee3"]
```

In above, myMapField should have type string key to string value and the keys in it should be a subset of values from myArrayField based on some conditional filtering.

Below is the validation schema that works for the array field and now I want to add the validation for map field.

```
const validationSchema = Yup.object().shape({
   myArrayField: Yup.array()
        .of(Yup.string())
        .min(1, 'This Field is Required')
        .required('This Field is Required'),
   myMapField: Yup. // some validation here to check type of key-value and check keys of myMapField to be subset of values in myArrayField
});
```

How can I add this validation for myMapField, given there is no Yup.map()?

Comment: could you give me some example

Comment: check out my answer. Is it solve your question?

Comment: Getting an error in validation- `"must be a object type, but the final value was: null (cast from the value {}). If "null" is intended as an empty value be sure to mark the schema as .nullable()"` , so trying to fix that. I've set initialValues as `new Map()`, but not sure why it is converting that to null. I'll mark your solution as accepted once I get this working.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Schema.test](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yup#schematestname-string-message-string--function--any-test-function-schema) for custom validation

And then using `this.parent` to access the `myArrayField` value (arrow function is not valid here)

Finally using js to check if map is valid like you desire.

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape({
  myArrayField: yup
    .array()
    .of(yup.string())
    .min(1, "This Field is Required")
    .required("This Field is Required"),

  myMapField: yup.object().test("validMap", "Map is invalid", function (val) {
    const arrayFieldValue = this.parent.myArrayField;

    // check function
    const isValid = Object.keys(val).every((key) => arrayFieldValue.includes(key));

    return isValid;
  }),
});
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/yup-validation-test-forked-sv999x?layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfh00063j6lxo8li45a%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfg00023j6l1zyxqc9k%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfh00033j6lxo4c00fq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfh00053j6ldp29v2gq%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B50%252C50%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clsvhclfg00023j6l1zyxqc9k%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfg00023j6l1zyxqc9k%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%257D%252C%2522clsvhclfh00053j6ldp29v2gq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfh00043j6lkfqx07zz%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522UNASSIGNED_PORT%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A0%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252F%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfh00053j6ldp29v2gq%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfh00043j6lkfqx07zz%2522%257D%252C%2522clsvhclfh00033j6lxo4c00fq%2522%253A%257B%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%255D%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clsvhclfh00033j6lxo4c00fq%2522%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D)

Comment: You can simplify a lot the `isInvalid` logic by directly return `return Object.keys(val).every((key) => arrayFieldValue.includes(key));`

Comment: For this particular case performance is not really a topic. If you don't have thousands elements in the myMapField then you won't see any difference and you should rather focus on the code readability. Keep in mind the “Make It Work, Make It Right, Make It Fast” principle.

Comment: For adding validations for map values, should following work?
`const allValuesSelected = Object.values(map).every(val => val !== undefined);`

Comment: You can check both key and value `Object.keys(val).every((key) => arrayFieldValue.includes(key) && Boolean(val[key]));`